# Setup Katzer cordova-plugin-local-notifications to run PhoneGap Build project on iOS Device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, localnotification

I am developing a cross-platform "hybrid" mobile app (HTML, CSS, JS) via PhoneGap Build and want it to send ***daily local notifications*** that show at least a snippet of a daily message from the home/1st page.

I included in the config.xml file the below plugins. Not sure if I need to include "gap:" or not.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast"  spec="2.6.0" source="npm" />
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="0.8.5" source="npm" />
```

(side note: I installed Katzer's Example-X on iOS, but it does not work. None of the buttons seem to be hooked up to demo.)

I grabbed some code from Katzer's Example-X and put in index.js:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    app.pluginInitialize();
    app.bindNotificationEvents();
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},
// Initialize plugin
pluginInitialize: function() {
    document.getElementById('granted').onclick         = app.hasPermission;
    document.getElementById('request').onclick         = app.askPermission;
    document.getElementById('sched_single').onclick    = app.scheduleSingle

        },
// Check permissions to read accounts
hasPermission: function () {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) {
        showToast(granted ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    });
},

    // Schedule a single notification
scheduleSingle: function () {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test Message',
        text: 'My first notification',
        icon: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Qdsy-GpempY/UU_BN9LTqSI/AAAAAAAAAMA/LkwLW2yNBJ4/s1600/supersu.png',
        smallIcon: 'res://cordova',
        sound: null,
        badge: 1,
        data: { test: 1 }
    });
},


var dialog;

showToast = function (text) {
var isMac = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('macintosh');

setTimeout(function () {
    if (window.Windows !== undefined) {
        showWinDialog(text);
    } else
    if (!isMac && window.plugins && window.plugins.toast) {
        window.plugins.toast.showShortBottom(String(text));
    }
    else {
        alert(text);
    }
}, 500);
};

showWinDialog = function (text) {
if (dialog) {
    dialog.content = text;
    return;
}

dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(text);

dialog.showAsync().done(function () {
    dialog = null;
});
};

if (window.hasOwnProperty('Windows')) {
alert = showWinDialog;
}

app.initialize();
```

In HTML file, I added

```
<h2 class="section">Permissions</h2>
<div class="container">
    <a id="granted" class="button">Granted?</a>
    <a id="request" class="button grey">Request</a>
</div>
<h2 class="section">Schedule</h2>
<div class="container">
<a id="sched_single" class="button orange">Single</a>
```

And at the end, just above closing tag for "body" I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

What am I supposed to do to get the plugin to work on a test iOS device? (It also should work on Android and Windows, but right now focusing on an iOS build.)

I have been reading through the wiki for [katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). No good, easy tutorial/video out there, at least none that I've found, to straightforward show newbie how to implement.

Comment: Hi - how familiar are you with push notifications? It requires a long explanation, with differences between different mobile operating systems.

Comment: Hi Michael. Only as familiar from end user POV. Brand new developer to mobile apps.

Comment: Been looking for solutions to get local notification working. Have downloaded Katzer's Example-X on iOS. It shows, but NOTHING works.

Comment: Still working out an answer for this. I followed a YouTube video by Ravi Bedre using my Mac because I need it for now on iOS. IT WORKED!!!! Great tutorial.  Just have to be patient going through it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsdLn07eq2g    I then added to the function "  every: "minute"   "   And that is working!   Now I need to add to my project, hopefully I can do this without Cordova because it is an existing project. After that, I would like for to add data that is linked to a calendar-based script to pull certain messages for certain days.  FOR NOW, the YouTube video link works.